# Anidar IF para mostrar control

Tags: office365, powerapps

Tengo un formulario con un botón de alternar. Quiero mostrar el botón sólo si se en otros dos campos del formulario hay un determinado valor. No tengo claro como anidar los IF para que el botón se muestre o no. Hasta hora solo he conseguido hacerlo con un campo, pero si quiero evaluar más campos me pierdo...

Tengo esto montado:

```
If(DataCardValue4.Selected.Value="SWAP"|| DataCardValue4.Selected.Value="Lending";true;false)
```

Pero además necesito que evalúe el campo DataCardValue5 = "Hecho" y DataCardValue3 = "MAIL".

¿Cómo podría hacerlo?

Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pues era más sencillo de lo imaginaba:

En la propiedad Visible del campo a mostrar/ocultar he añadido la siguiente fórmula, que "anida" varios AND en un IF. Comprueba que se cumplan una serie de condiciones y que además se compruebe que, al menos, hay un archivo adjunto:

```
If((DataCardValue4.Selected.Value="MAIL"|| DataCardValue4.Selected.Value="AVISO") && DataCardValue6.Selected.Value="Preparacion" && DataCardValue7.Selected.Value="Terminada" && DataCardValue11.Selected.Value="NCX-40" && CountRows(DataCardValue13.Attachments) > 0;true;false)
```

Con eso sólo muestro el campo si se cumplen todas las condiciones del IF.